# phpinfo doesnt show the content on chrome/firefox browser

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2, lamp

I am learning the MVC framework on codeigniter. In that regard I wanted to get going with the lamp server running on my localhost. I have all the necessary packages installed ( MySQL, php5, apache2). Apache2 is running in the background.

`root      8771  0.0  0.0  71296  2064 ?        Ss   Apr22   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data  8773  0.0  0.0 688252  2324 ?        Sl   Apr22   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  www-data  8774  0.0  0.0 557228  1980 ?        Sl   Apr22   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`

Under /var/www, I created a file i.e. info.php with `phpinfo()` being called.

Although when I go to localhost/info.php, it shows me the script but doesn't display the actual phpinfo I am looking for. (On just typing localhost it displays all the info from apache2.conf located in /etc/apache2)

My system:
`Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`

I don't know if there is any configuration issue with apache or something else.

Any ideas/help will be really appreciated.

Comment: can you add the script code?

Comment: `<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>`

Answer (score 0):

Does your browser ask if you want to download the php file instead of displaying it? If Apache is not actually parsing the php after you restarted it, install libapache2-mod-php5. It is installed when you install the php5 package, but may have been removed inadvertently by packages which need to run a different version of php.

Comment: Yes, libapache-mod-php5 is installed. The browser doesn't ask for downloading any file. It just prints out the content of info.php ( on doing http://localhost/info.php).

Comment: I am not sure if the config file ( apache2.conf under /var/www/) needs to be edited to accept/display php files. I am wondering so, because index.html displays under /var/www/html/ displays everything in its content.

Comment: Add php5 to the variable APACHE_MODULES in the configuration file:
    `a2enmod php5`,
and then restart apache2

Comment: And where is this file located?

Comment: you should read [server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/serverguide.pdf),
the configuration file is probably under /etc/apache2/

Comment: Got it working. Under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled , the DocumentRoot was pointing to /var/www/html but my info.php file was on /var/www/. So changed it to /var/www and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php

the module is installed, but not enabled.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+enable+php+for+apache

Please follow the guide on Ubuntu to complete your installation.